# Make character jump smooth

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, physics

I'm working on run-jump game and I tried to make character jump smooth but it's look like the character is fly and not jump

(Video attached in end of topic)

touchesBegan func

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    //Check if the user is on PlayScene

    if scene?.name == "PlayScene" {

    //start timer on touch
    TouchTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerStart), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

for touch: AnyObject in touches {

    //If the Game is NOT Over!
    if isgameOver != true {

        //Before first touch
        if (isFirstBlock == true) {

            //Tap first time
            isFirstBlock = false

            //Call Run Action
            self.ojiRunFunc(sprite: ojiGame, name: "OjiRun")
            ojiGame.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
            spawn = SKAction.run({
                () in
                self.createBlocks()
            })

            let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)
            let spawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
            let spawnDelayforever = SKAction.repeatForever(spawnDelay)
            self.run(spawnDelayforever)

        }

        playSound(soundName: "Jump")
        ojiGame.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = 0
        jumpActionfunc()
        //**********************************************************//

        //The game is OVER!
    } else {
        TouchTimer.invalidate()
    }
```

timerStart func

```
func timerStart() {
    //Add time
    timeTouch = timeTouch + 0.1
    jumpActionfunc()
}
```

jumpActionFunc

```
func jumpActionfunc () {

    if (timeTouch <= 0.1 && timeTouch <= 0.2) {
        ojiGame.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 30))
        print("1")
    }else if (timeTouch >= 0.3 && timeTouch <= 0.4) {
        ojiGame.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 10))
        print("2")
    }else if (timeTouch >= 0.5 && timeTouch <= 0.6) {
        ojiGame.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 15))
        print("3")
    }else if (timeTouch >= 0.7 && timeTouch <= 0.8) {
        ojiGame.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 20))
        print("4")
    }

}
```

touchesEnded func

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    ojiGame.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -12))
    //Reset timer after touch ended
    TouchTimer.invalidate()
    timeTouch = 0.0

}
```

Video:
[here's the jump in my game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fK30lMHcvVM)

Comment: It looks ok to me.  The only thing I would say is when you have a longer jump he stays at the same vertical height too long.  Try changing your Impulse amount to be variable based on how long he has been in the air.

Comment: These are very long (relative to general game input) amounts of time for the long touches for higher jumps. So this will kind of feel like flying because the "going up, cause player still holding jump button" is so long. Usually a long jump is a very short space of time, something like a matter of frames rather than a matter of full tenths of a second.

Comment: It's not good jump because when I tap on screen is always go to 0.1 condition and after to all conditions (depending on tap time) and it's make the character fly and not jump.

Comment: If you always get to the first condition the value of `timeTouch` is not what you would expect. I suggest printing them and see if they are reasonable.

Comment: The timeTouch is change but in first time it must equal 0.1 and after timeTouch is increase.

Comment: @AviRok I don't think I understand your problem. If the `timeTouch` variable increases properly, then your `dy: ..` values should be changed. Also, shouldn't the first condition be `timeTouch >= 0.1 && timeTouch <= 0.2` (note the change in the first condition, `>=`)